# Maven build parent before other modules

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-profiles

I have a maven project with following structure

```
parent
  -pom.xml
  -module1
     -pom.xml
  -module2
     -pom.xml
```

In parent I have a profile with plugin to be executed recursively for all child modules. But when I build the project I found that the child modules are build first and finally the parent. But I want the opposite to happen. I want the plugin to be executed first for parent and then for child modules. Because only when the plugin is executed in parent, a file which is to be consumed by child modules will be generated. So if the child modules build first then the plugin execution is skipped as file is missing.

Comment: Please show the log file cause the parent is the first one which is build at the beginning ...btw: Are you testing on plain command line ? Which Maven version do you use? JDK version?

Comment: jdk 1.8 and mvn 3.6.1

Answer (score 4):

An ofter misunderstood concept in Maven is the difference between `parent` and `aggregator`. [This article](http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/12/maven-aggregator-vs-parent.html) throws some more light on it. In reality often the same project plays the role of both `parent` and `aggregator` which I assume is also your case.

If so, you can not expect the `aggregator` "to be executed first" as its whole "execution" is basically boiling down to executing the sub-modules.

What may help in you case is to separate the `parent` from the `aggregator`. So you will have a structure like this:

```
aggregator
  - pom.xml (where you have <modules>...<modules>)
  - parent
     -pom.xml (no parent)
  - module1
     -pom.xml (parent is `parent` and not `aggregator`)
  - module2
     -pom.xml (parent is `parent` and not `aggregator`)
```

This way you can put the `parent` to be the first module in your `<modules>...<modules>` and it can generate the file before other modules are built.

**Things to keep in mind:**

- This will only work if you execute the reactor build (the aggregator). It will not work if you build individual modules as it will not trigger the parent build.
- Parent-child relationship is probably not the best way to solve this. Consider converting the parent to regular project that produces artifact and put the generated file in it. Then add that project as dependency in the modules and make the plugin use the file from the dependent artifact. That way you will also solve the previously mentioned issue.

**UPDATE:**

Looks like something has changed in Maven or perhaps I remember it wrong. I did a quick check (Maven 3.5.0) with the following structure

```
- project A 
 - pom.xml (type pom, has <modules><module>B</module><module>C</module></modules>)
 - project B
   - pom.xml (has parent A)
 - project C
   - pom.xml (no parent)
```

the result when I run `mvn` on `A` is:

```
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] C
[INFO] A
[INFO] B
```

It seams that if a module specifies a parent (even if the parent is the reactor) the parent will be processed before the module. Given the clarification in the comment (that your modules currently don't have parent) probably the easiest fix is to add the `reactor` as `parent`.

That however may result in other issues and the "things to keep in mind" above are still valid.

Comment: According to what you have said the parent module to which I referred is only an aggregator. It do not have any src code of its own. So I cannot use the above solution. I want to build aggregator first and children afterwards.
`aggregator
 
  - pom.xml (where you have <modules>...<modules>)
 
  - module1
 
     -pom.xml (no parent and not aggregator)
 
  - module2
 
     -pom.xml (no parent and not aggregator)`

Comment: @DevikaSudheer I updated the answer. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the exec sequence is different in Windows env or in Linux env. The following structure

```
- project A 
 - pom.xml (type pom, has <modules><module>B</module><module>C</module></modules>)
 - project B
   - pom.xml (has parent A)
 - project C
   - pom.xml (no parent)
```

executes as sequence C, A, B in Windows,
but as sequence B, C, A in Linux. 
Indeed I don't care when C is packaged, but the problem is the difference sequence of A and B. When I use the plugin "flatten-maven-plugin", in Linux, it will not replace the property ${revision} in project B, because it's defined in project A but A is build last. So B will fail as it tries to resolve its parent of output "a-${revision}.pom".

Answer (score 0):

I am posting possible cause when parent module is not build first.

Make sure that **all your modules have the same parent version**.

Probably this could help someone as it seems that there is no easy way to detect this case. The only visible effect is that parent module is not first in *Reactor Build Order*.